# Can i echo hidden field under <select>

Tags: php

I do not know if it makes sense but i am trying to `echo` a hidden field in select box but does not work. How can i echo

```
echo "<input name='testt' type='hidden' id='testt' value='".$ver["cats_fee"]."'>";
```

in here:

```
<select size="1" name="parentcat">
    <option value='0'>---- Top Category ----</option>
    <?
    $al=mysql_query("select * from cats where cats_parentid='0' order by cats_id desc");
    while($ver=mysql_fetch_array($al))
    {

        echo "<option value='".$ver["cats_id"]."'>".$ver["cats_name"]."</option>";
                $al2=mysql_query("select * from cats where cats_parentid='".$ver["cats_id"]."' order by cats_id desc");

        while($ver2=mysql_fetch_array($al2))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$ver2["cats_id"]."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;> ".$ver2["cats_name"]."</option>";

        }
    }

    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't put an form element into another form element, this makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to pass $ver["cats_name"] value according to selected option field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send multiple pieces of data based on a user-selection. It's easier just to send the unique id (as you are already doing) then lookup the 'fee', along with any other data you need' in the script that the form sends to.

As an aside, it also looks like you are making many database calls to, effectively, get all cats back. If that's true, it's probably more efficient to just get them all with a single call and handle the hierarchy in your script.

Comment: I am going to do that way. I am getting the category id so it will be easy enough I was just wondering if you could send multiple data under select box.

Comment: @baris22: in theory you could - for example, you could set the value of each option to something like "id:name:age", then split the value into individual fields in the target script. This could easily get pretty messy, though, so I wouldn't really recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see which option the user is selecting on the `client side` when you are at the `server side`. The solution is using javascript - which is a `client side` language, search like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=select%20onchange) or [this](http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=detect%20select%20value%20javascript) would help alot I think.

Answer (score 0):

Because both the select box, ancd an input field are form elements, you can't nest them. But because you only use hidden input fields for storing data on your page, out of sight for the user, it doesn't really matter where you place it, as long as it's inside the form.

Comment: when i put anywhere i want it does not work. i do not get the value i wanted. i need to get the value that user choosen.